# How can you output properties that were NOT mapped using Value Injecter?

Tags: c#, .net, automapping, valueinjecter

I am using [Value Injecter](https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to map DTO->VM and vice versa.

Since all models and DTOs are still very much under development, I was wondering if there is a way to output the source object's property names/values that were NOT mapped to the target object, so I can verify the names of the properties match?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by: "output the properties in an object"

Comment: @Omu I meant to output the source's property names that were not mapped to the target, for debugging purposes via Debug.WriteLine(...)

Comment: you could do that in a unit test by checking the values manually, if it has the same value then probably it wasn't set (it might have been set but with the same value)

Comment: @Omu thanks, and there is no way to do this "on the fly"? By the way, I've seen a sample "AreEqual" injection that checks if the property values are equal in SetValue(). I would need the opposite. Thanks again.

Comment: maybe use the clone injection to create a copy, map/inject,  and after use a modified areequal which would output properties that aren't equal